# What's the best practice of simple Slick INSERT/GET?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick-3.0

I need to use Slick 3.1.1 for a Postgres based project, but I have a hard time to write clean code for the following super simple usage:

Assume I have a `Task` model:

```
case class Task(id: Option[UUID], foo: Int, bar: String)
```

The `id: UUID` is the primary key, so I should NOT provide it (`id = None`) when doing database INSERT. However, I do need it when doing GET which maps a database row to a Task object.

Therefore, the Slick Table class becomes very ugly:

```
class Tasks(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "tasks") {

  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.SqlType("UUID"), O.PrimaryKey)

  def foo = column[Int]("foo")

  def bar = column[String]("bar")

  def insert: MappedProjection[Task, (Int, String)] =
    (foo, bar).shaped.<>(
      { tuple =>
        Task.tupled(None, tuple._1, tuple._2)
      }, { (task: Task) =>
        Task.unapply(task).map { tuple =>
          (tuple._2, tuple._3)
        }
      }
    )

  override def * : ProvenShape[Task] =
    (id.?,
      foo,
      bar).shaped.<>(Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
}
```

If case class Task has 10 elements, I then have to write `(tuple._1, tuple._2, tuple._3, ......)` My co-workers will slap my face if I submit a PR like above. Please suggest!

Comment: You can define that on the database level. Check the docs at http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting . "When you include an AutoInc column in an insert operation, it is silently ignored, so that the database can generate the proper value." Meaning you can pass a dummy value and the db will auto increment the id

Comment: I noticed that in the document. But I feel this may make the code less straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll let the database to autoincrement your IDs, that Table definition could be shortened significantly:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import java.util.UUID

case class Task(id: Option[UUID], foo: Int, bar: String)

class Tasks(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "tasks") {
  def id = column[Option[UUID]]("id", O.SqlType("UUID"), O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def foo = column[Int]("foo")
  def bar = column[String]("bar")

  def * = (id, foo, bar) <> (Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
}
```

This could be improved further by moving the `id` field to the end of the case class and giving it the default `None` value. This way you won't have to provide it every time you want to instantiate the `Task`:

```
case class Task(foo: Int, bar: String, id: Option[UUID] = None)

val firstTask = Task(123, "John")
val secondTask = Task(456, "Paul")
```

Comment: I got an compilation error like: ```[error]  found   : ((Int, String)) => models.Task
[error]  required: ((Int, String, Option[UUID])) => ?
[error]       ).shaped.<>(Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
[error]                              ^
```

Comment: It looks like you're not using `id` in your `def *` method. Could you post your code here?